# app hide() and show() method alternative for linux and window

Tags: javascript, electron

`app.hide()` and `app.show()` according to the documentation work only for macOS, is there other method to `hide` and `show` the mainWindow using the [`app`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with `app` object, there is a hide method on `win` object, that works cross platform.

You can just call `win.hide()`.

see:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winhide